# I am trying to set up Kafka in my local mac

Tags: apache-kafka

I have unzipped the kafka_2.12-2.5.0 version and started zookeeper and when I am trying to start kafka using the command 
"bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties" i am getting the following eror:

/Users/manig/Desktop/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 317: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home#/bin/java: No such file or directory
/Users/manig/Desktop/kafka_2.12-2.5.0/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 317: exec: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home#/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory.

I tried adding double quotes around the JAVA term like this: "$JAVA" and also changing the classpath to `cygpath -wp $CLASSPATH` but still getting the same above error

can someone please help me with this..!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your Java ClassPath properly using the below commands. It was not able to recognize you JDK.

```
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

Comment: Kafka doesn't require Java 8

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  After adding this i am still getting new errors as below:                 Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

`cygpath` is for Cygwin, not Mac.

If you want to install on a Mac, just use [`brew install kafka`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/kafka#default)

Or [use Docker](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html)